# Difference between two columns with only sign

Tags: excel

I have two columns and want to calculate difference between the two columns (ie B1-A1) in Excel. However I only want to indicate whether the difference is positive or negative in third column.

A sample of my data in Excel looks like this:

```
8438    8510
3709    3181
```

Here I want to calculate the difference between two columns using formula
C1 =(B1-A1)

But I want to only indicate the sign  as shown below:

```
8438    8510  +
3709    3181  -
```

Please advise?

Answer (score 1):

Just use an [IF statement](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) that returns the sign you want. For example

```
=IF(A1 > B1,"+","-")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use Number Formatting.

Select all of column C by clicking its column header.

Right-click and select `Format cells...`.

Click on the `Number` tab and select `Custom` from the list on the left.

In the `Type:` field enter this: `+;-`

Click OK.

That's it. Now when you use YOUR formula in column C, the numeric answer will display exactly has you have envisioned.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `IF()` function, it takes three parameters:

```
=IF([condition], [result if true], [result if false])
```

So your example would be:

```
=IF(B1 > A1, "+", "-")
```